# How to run a contiki project in cooja?

Tags: contiki

I'm Parvin, a postgraduate student.

I want to, Glossy, which is a project of Contiki,run in Cooja, And see the results. But the results are not seen in collect view.
I am a rookie. I searched on the Internet but could not find a solution to my problem. please guide me.
Thank you
Parvin

Comment: Glossy download link:
https://sourceforge.net/code-snapshots/svn/c/co/contikiprojects/code/contikiprojects-code-322.zip
Look to ethz folder.

Comment: Even if you manage to run it you probably won't see results that make sense. Cooja is not good at modeling the RF propagation features that are required by Glossy: constructive interference and the capture effect (it has only partial support for the capture effect). I suggest to rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback
But it might explain further.
I've got files Glossy which is environment Contiki.
On the other hand, Glossy is for WSN.
Cooja is also to WSN.
So why not Cooja?
and
How do I test Glossy in Cooja. And I report?

Comment: In a StackOverflow question, you need to say what you have done so far and what specific problem are you having.

Comment: I want to see statistical results and graphs of the simulation protocol in cooja. I can see this charts for other codes in the contiki example folder but i dont see it for glossy